# Cannot get Spring MVC 4.0.0 to serve jsp under /WEB-INF/pages on Tomcat7

Tags: spring, jsp, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA 12 and trying to run a simple HelloWorld Spring MVC app. While web/index.jsp doesn't have an issue, I cannot get the /WEB-INF/pages/hello.jsp to display correctly (I'm using `http://localhost:8080/hello` ). I keep getting:

> HTTP Status 404 -
>
> type Status report
>
> message
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

Below is my setup. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

**1. Project Structure**

```
--src
  --main
    --java
      --com.beingjavaguys.controller
        --HomeController.java
--web
  --WEB-INF
    --pages
      --hello.jsp
    --spring-servlet.xml
    --web.xml
  --index.jsp
--pom.xml
```

**2. HomeController:**

```
package com.beingjavaguys.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

 @RequestMapping("/hello")
 public ModelAndView test() {
    String message = "Welcome to Spring 4.0 !";
    return new ModelAndView("/hello.jsp", "message", message);
 }
}
```

**3. hello.jsp:**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Being Java Guys | Hello World</title> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>Being Java Guys | Hello World</h2>
  <h4>${message}</h4>
 </body>
</html>
```

**4. spring-servlet.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.beingjavaguys.controller"/>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

**5. web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">

<display-name>Spring4MVC</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

  </web-app>
```

**6. index.jsp:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Being Java Guys | Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Being Java Guys | Hello World</h2>
<h4><a href="hello.html">Click Here</a></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

**7. Maven dependencies:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>TestSpring4</groupId>
<artifactId>TestSpring4</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>TestSpring4</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- Shared version number properties -->
    <org.springframework.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Core utilities used by other modules.
        Define this if you use Spring Utility APIs
        (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core)
        Define this if you use Spring Expression APIs
        (org.springframework.expression.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core)
        Define this if you use Spring Bean APIs
        (org.springframework.beans.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Application Context
        (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, spring-beans)
        This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection Container
        and is generally always defined-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, Quartz,
        and Freemarker integration
        Define this if you need any of these integrations-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and
        Portlet Environments
        (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
        Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another
        web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments
        (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
        Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet Container such as
        Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning

```
return new ModelAndView("/hello.jsp", "message", message);
```

That means the view name is `/hello.jsp`. Spring will use the `ViewResolver` you registered. That's

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The prefix and suffix will be applied and your view name will be resolved to

```
/WEB-INF/pages//hello.jsp.jsp
```

which doesn't exist.

You should be returning a view name of simply `hello`.

```
return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
```

Now it will be resolved

```
/WEB-INF/pages/hello.jsp
```

which exists and a `RequestDispatcher` can forward to it.

Don't forget to add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

and the corresponding namespace declarations in your servlet context configuration, otherwise the Spring MVC stack won't register your `@Controller` beans as handlers.

---

Make this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

provided by the container

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

otherwise you might get some jar hell problems as the `jstl` library is typically already included  by the Servlet container.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but I'm still getting the same error message when accessing http://localhost:8080/hello : HTTP Status 404 -

   type Status report

   message

   description The requested resource is not available.-

Comment: @Christian Add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to your `spring-servlet.xml` configuration. Without it, controllers are not registered. You'll need the corresponding namespace.

Comment: Added that as well, still not working. Could this be a WAR packaging issue? I'm fairly new to using Intellij IDEA.

Comment: @Christian I doubt it. You can always check. Produce a WAR, check its contents with a ZIP file manager. Your class files and resources should be in `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: I double-checked WEB-INF/classes and there were some issues with the WAR packaging. I re-created the WAR profile and it worked. Thank you!